# table deletion and re-create in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS which in order to work has to have some specific tables. Therefore I have made an "Execute Sql Task" package which first verifies if table exists and has the specific number of columns, if not then the existing table is being dropped and then re-created with needed columns.
 Bottom line is that my sql script looks like this (in the same "execute sql task" package):

```
declare @nr integer;
set @nr=(select COUNT (*) 
         from dbo.syscolumns 
         where id= (select id 
                    from dbo.sysobjects 
                    where id = object_id(N'[bogdan].[dbo].[my_table]') 
                    and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1));

if (@nr<>10 and @nr<>0) /*to verify if my_table exists and has the required number of     colums - 10 */
    drop table [bogdan].[dbo].[my_table]
go

declare @nr1 integer;
set @nr1=(select count(*) 
          from dbo.sysobjects 
          where id = object_id(N'[bogdan].[dbo].[My_table]') 
          and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1);
if @nr1=0  
create table bogdan.dbo.my_table (....) on [PRIMARY]
go

/*end of script*/
```

The problem is that even when I have dropped the table (my_table from the example above), there is still an object named "my_table" in sysobjects. The @nr1 variable has 1 as its value, instead of 0 therefore the table with needed structure is not created, as if clause does not get executed.

Any hints?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure your table is being dropped? What if `@nr = 10`. You're only doing the drop if there `@nr is not zero` and `@nr is not 10`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I dropped myself from Sql Server. If @nr=10 it supposed to do nothing because it exists and it has the right columns.

Comment: @BogdanM : Your query is perfect. It should work. If possible please post your original query. That will may help us to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and you will know for sure if your table is actually being dropped:

```
declare @nr integer;
set @nr=(select COUNT (*) 
         from dbo.syscolumns 
         where id= (select id 
                    from dbo.sysobjects 
                    where id = object_id(N'[bogdan].[dbo].[my_table]') 
                    and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1));

if (@nr<>10 and @nr<>0) 
/*to verify if my_table exists and has the required number of     colums - 10 */
    begin
    drop table [bogdan].[dbo].[my_table]
    set @nr=0
    end

if @nr=0  
create table bogdan.dbo.my_table (....) on [PRIMARY]
go
```

Raj